# Broken ssl paths after build python app with py2app

Tags: python, ssl, py2app

I build python app with py2app.
In my app, i use urllib2 lib, urlopen and other methods.
But if i run app in another Mac(not default,when i build app).
Python except

```
SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
```

this error except in `urllib2.urlopen` method. And i think that error, because py2app does not set right path to ssl cert.
in app, i call

```
ssl.get_default_verify_paths()
```

and see that `cafile` and `capath` is `None`.
How can i set default_verify_paths in my app or i need build right app, may be with another options?